# Abuse (?) of SizedBox in flutter

Tags: flutter

Questions)

I use a SizedBox to create a gap between the widget and the widget.

When creating a specific UI, there was a situation where SizedBox was abused because the intervals were all different.

​

I have put a SizedBox between almost all Widgets and Widgets.

​

Do you have any recommendations for many uses of SizedBox in flutter?

​

Is there a performance issue or is not recommended?

​

Thank you ^^!

ex)

```
SizedBox(
    height: 10.0,
),
Container(),
SizedBox(
    height: 10.0,
),
Container(),
SizedBox(
    height: 10.0,
),
Container(),
```

Comment: provide some code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres no issue, use `SizedBox` to your hearts content, if the `SizedBox` does not have any `child` it does not render anything it just takes some space, so you wont face any issues.,

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gap widget. No need to worry about width/height. It automatically gets it from it's parent.

Here's the link: https://pub.dev/packages/gap